# Positioning every second row of my hexagon grid differently?

Tags: css

How do I place every second row to fit in with the top row in my hexagon grid? 
I used nth-of-type to create the equal spacing but now I need to somehow manage to target all hexagons of every second row. I could change my html markup but prefer to keep things clean with nth-of-type or nth-child.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QweBra

First css for spacing works.

```
#categories li:nth-of-type(1n+1){
  margin:0 1em;
}
#categories li:nth-of-type(6n+6){
  margin:2em 9em;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Responsive grid of hexagons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114920/responsive-grid-of-hexagons)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap every row in another `div`, and then move every `#category div:nth-of-type(2n)` to where you wanted them.

Comment: I thought of doing that too. Seems the best way

Answer (score 0):

Short of adding something like this to your CSS (while it uses `nth-of-type`, it's not really "clean"), you'd need to re-organize your markup, or use JavaScript.

```
#categories li:nth-of-type(6), #categories li:nth-of-type(7), #categories li:nth-of-type(8), #categories li:nth-of-type(9), #categories li:nth-of-type(10){
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
    left: 95px;
}

#categories li:nth-of-type(11), #categories li:nth-of-type(12) {
    position: relative;
    top: -80px;
}
```

There is most likely a JavaScript library that exists for this (several, probably).