# CSS styling a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

I'm trying to apply some style to an anchor tag `<a>` without success, I want to create a URL in the first hexagon with the style of the other hexagons. I need to have MyURL styled like "This is a title" in the other hexagons.

```
  <li>
    <div>
    <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2878/10944255073_973d2cd25c.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1><a href="#">MyURL</a></h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </div>
  </li>
```

(solved) pen -> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZNWGN

This is based on the thread below:

[Responsive grid of hexagons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114920/responsive-grid-of-hexagons)

Can anyone give me some help?

Comment: You can't apply style to a URL.  You can apply style to an anchor element, and if you post the styles you've created for your <a> tags, someone can probably tell you why they aren't working.

Comment: Thanks Dave I wanted to say a anchor tag, will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's inheriting `position:absolute` from the styles  for `#categories li *`. Override it by adding:

```
#categories li h1 * { position: relative; }
```

Alternatively, replace `#categories li *` with something more specific.

Comment: #categories li a seems to work

Comment: `#categories li *` is not an efficient selector. CSS parses selectors starting from the _RIGHT_... This means the `*` will select ALL elements on the page, and then see if it has a parent `li`, better to target some specific elements, rather than `*`. See: [Why do browsers match CSS selectors from right to left?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/why-do-browsers-match-css-selectors-from-right-to-left)

Comment: It's a micro-optimization, and not one I would worry about in practice. Either way, the better solution is to replace `#categories li *` with something more specific.

Answer (score 0):

In all the other exagon the title is in :

```
<h1>Title</h1>
```

But In the first one you are placing the title in an a tag like so:

```
<a href="#">This is a title</a>
```

An this will cause the problem

Comment: but the `a` is inside a `h1`

Comment: Of course but you didn't pay attention about what @Dave also sad in his comment. In other words your 'css' can currently properly allign the <h1> tag and not the 'a' tag.

Comment: @Blazemonger has the right answer ;)