# how can i use hexagon in isotope jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css

[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROj1a.png)

this is isotope jquery plugin. when click in isotope menu list item change both side (left paragraph and right hexagon image).check the image & suggest me how can i do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114920/responsive-grid-of-hexagons/26116497#26116497