# Responsive grid of hexagons in native ios

Tags: ios, native

I want to use this technique: [Responsive grid of hexagons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114920/responsive-grid-of-hexagons) in a native ios applications. How can I do that? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Check out here, if it help:[https://github.com/piemonte/PBJHexagon](https://github.com/piemonte/PBJHexagon).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive grid of hexagons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114920/responsive-grid-of-hexagons)