# Hover effect does not fully cover element in my hexagonal grid

Tags: jquery, css

Based on this [very good response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114920/responsive-grid-of-hexagons), I am experimenting with a responsive CSS hexagonal grid for images.

I installed the CSS identical to that [on Github except](https://github.com/web-tiki/responsive-grid-of-hexagons) for one thing: I removed media queries that would have allowed rows of hexagons longer than 3.

That said, when the grid renders, the hexagons appear and look great, but when I hover on them, the hexagon only partially fills in, as seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/p9810xdj/

I've tried checking padding and margins that I thought could be causing this empty space between the two halves, but no luck. Any clue why the hover effect is not functioning correctly:

```
/*** HOVER EFFECT  **********************************************************************/
.hexIn:hover h1, .hexIn:focus h1,
.hexIn:hover p, .hexIn:focus p{
    -webkit-transform:translateY(0%) translatez(-1px);
        -ms-transform:translateY(0%) translatez(-1px);
            transform:translateY(0%) translatez(-1px);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed something when checking the margins!

Added this to your css:

```
.hex h1, .hex p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

And the empty spaces were gone.

Comment: Dang it! Great fix. Thanks so much for the help. Confirming answer.