# How to add more padding between hexagons without losing responsiveness?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a personal website where I want to show hexagonal images/tiles on front page. I found a solution here for responsive hexagon html and css blocks.Now I want to add more padding between these hexagons without losing responsiveness.

I'd tried adding padding but it destroy overall responsiveness.

This is the original code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26116497/8621918).

I want more padding between two hexagons like padding of 15px or 20px.

Comment: please copy the code in snippet to help you

Comment: @ImenKrichen I'd given you the link, that's the exact code I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to have padding in pixels, but here is what worked for me,

```
.hexIn {
    width:86%;
    padding-bottom: 99.307%; /* =  width / sin(60) */
}
```

Reduce the value of width of the hexIn block and the padding accordingly. You can visually analyze the padding in-between the blocks, try reducing/increasing until you fill comfortable.

padding-bottom = (width * 2)/1.7320

Comment: very nice solution +1, tried to solve it with no success. if someone in the future will need all the example including your solution: https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=4419c3aa-bb46-49d0-bcda-a76c511e81fa

Comment: Working perfectly! Thank you so much!