# Hexagon Grid CSS - All hexagons change size when each of them is clicked

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have 8 hexagons made purely with HTML and CSS and the code is taken from [this example](https://github.com/web-tiki/responsive-grid-of-hexagons/blob/master/hexagons.css). However, I have inserted my own images in them.

**Problem:**

They all change sizes each time I click any of them.

**Functionality**:

I am showing different information on the other half of the page corresponding to each of the hexagons when clicked using `useState` React hook. Would that be the cause?

**What I've tried**:

1. The code is using `%`in CSS so, I changed it to `pixels` thinking it's a responsiveness issue but that didn't help
2. I used some other examples too however, that didn't help either

**Expected**:

When clicked on any hexagon, sizes shouldn't change

My first time posting so hope the structure above is as expected. Any help or tips will be much appreciated. Thanks

```css
#hexGrid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left:0px;
  width: 45%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.hex {
  position: relative;
  visibility:hidden;
  outline:1px solid transparent; /* fix for jagged edges in FF on hover transition */
}
.hex::after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  padding-bottom: 86.602%;  /* =  100 / tan(60) * 1.5 */
}
.hexIn{
  position: absolute;
  width:96%;
  padding-bottom: 110.851%; /* =  width / sin(60) */
  margin:0 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  outline:1px solid transparent; /* fix for jagged edges in FF on hover transition */
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,-60deg) skewY(30deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,-60deg) skewY(30deg);
          transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,-60deg) skewY(30deg);
}
.hexIn * {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  outline:1px solid transparent; /* fix for jagged edges in FF on hover transition */
}
.hexLink {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0,0,1,60deg);
        -ms-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0,0,1,60deg);
            transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0,0,1,60deg);
}

/*** HEX CONTENT **********************************************************************/
.hex img {
  left: -100%;
  right: -100%;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg);
          transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg);
}

.hex p {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ff7f50;
    font-weight: 300;
    -webkit-transition:  -webkit-transform .2s ease-out, opacity .3s ease-out;
    transition:          transform .2s ease-out, opacity .3s ease-out;
    opacity:0.8;
}

.hex p.cc {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #54a29b;
    font-weight: 300;
    -webkit-transition:  -webkit-transform .2s ease-out, opacity .3s ease-out;
    transition:          transform .2s ease-out, opacity .3s ease-out;
}
.hex h1 {
    width:100%;
    bottom: 35%;
    padding-top:50%;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    z-index: 1;
    color:#000;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,-100%,0);
        -ms-transform:translate3d(0,-100%,0);
            transform:translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}

.hex p {
  top: 58%;
  padding-bottom:60%;
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,100%,0);
      -ms-transform:translate3d(0,100%,0);
          transform:translate3d(0,100%,0);
}

/*** HOVER EFFECT  **********************************************************************/
.hexLink h1,
.hexLink:hover p {
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
      -ms-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
          transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
}

/*** HEXAGON SIZING AND EVEN ROW INDENTATION *****************************************************************/
@media (min-width:1201px) { /* <- 5-4  hexagons per row */
  #hexGrid{
    padding-bottom: 4.4%
  }
  .hex {
    width:30%; /* = 100 / 3 */
  }
  .hex:nth-child(9n+4){ /* first hexagon of even rows */
    margin-left: 15%;  /* = width of .hex / 2  to indent even rows */
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width:901px) { /* <- 4-3  hexagons per row */
  #hexGrid{
    padding-bottom: 5.5%
  }
  .hex {
    width: 25%; /* = 100 / 4 */
  }
  .hex:nth-child(7n+5){ /* first hexagon of even rows */
    margin-left:12.5%;  /* = width of .hex / 2  to indent even rows */
  }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) and (min-width:601px) { /* <- 3-2  hexagons per row */
  #hexGrid{
    padding-bottom: 7.4%
  }
  .hex {
    width: 33.333%; /* = 100 / 3 */
  }
  .hex:nth-child(5n+4){ /* first hexagon of even rows */
    margin-left:16.666%;  /* = width of .hex / 2  to indent even rows */
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) { /* <- 2-1  hexagons per row */
  #hexGrid{
    padding-bottom: 11.2%
  }
  .hex {
    width: 50%; /* = 100 / 3 */
  }
  .hex:nth-child(3n+3){ /* first hexagon of even rows */
    margin-left:25%;  /* = width of .hex / 2  to indent even rows */
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
    #hexGrid {
        font-size: 13px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="hexGrid">
    <li class="hex">
        <div class="hexIn">
            <a class="hexLink" onClick={displayText1Content}>
                <img src="../../../../assets/images/hex-orange.png" />
                <h1>Text1</h1>
                <p>Click to learn more</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="hex">
        <div class="hexIn">
            <a class="hexLink" onClick={displayText2ontent}>
                <img  src="../../../../assets/images/hex-orange.png" />
                <h1>Text2</h1>
                <p>Click to learn more</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="hex">
        <div class="hexIn">
            <a class="hexLink" onClick={displayReportsContent}>
                <img src="../../../../assets/images/hex-orange.png" />
                <h1>Text3</h1>
                <p>Click to learn more</p>
            </a>
        </div>
     </li>
     <li class="hex">
        <div class="hexIn">
            <a class="hexLink" onClick={displayText4Content}>
                <img src="../../../../assets/images/hex-blue2.png" />
                <h1>Text4</h1>
                <p>Click to learn more</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="hex">
        <div class="hexIn">
            <a class="hexLink" onClick={displayText5Content}>
                <img src="../../../../assets/images/hex-blue2.png" />
                <h1>Text5</h1>
                <p>Click to learn more</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="hex">
        <div class="hexIn">
            <a class="hexLink" onClick={displayText6Content}>
                <img src="../../../../assets/images/hex-orange.png" />
                <h1>Text6</h1>
                <p>Click to learn more</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="hex">
        <div class="hexIn">
            <a class="hexLink" onClick={displayText7Content}>
                <img src="../../../../assets/images/hex-orange.png" />
                <h1>Text7</h1>
                <p>Click to learn more</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="hex">
        <div class="hexIn">
            <a class="hexLink" onClick={displayText8Content}>
                <img src="../../../../assets/images/hex-orange.png" />
                <h1>Text8</h1>
                <p>Click to learn more</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: I copied and pasted it into the Snippet helper as is. Changed nothing. Would there be anything in the `onClick` methods that would be causing the problem?

Comment: I noticed that and then deleted my comment. Thanks for that

Comment: I thought so too but nothing abnormal showing in the console when I click. Maybe something to do with `useState` hook?

Comment: try this implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65684164/8620333 easier and with less of code

Comment: Thanks @Temani. Will try that after I finish my current task and keep you posted.

Comment: @Temani, I just tried that solution you pointed me to and the problem still exists