# How to put an image on top of inline svg via css without div?

Tags: html, css, svg

**I have a svg generated by javascript and included inline in the HTML page. On top (above, higher z-index) of some hexes (polygons defined in SVG) I want to display an image.**

I was able to do it adding a div containing the image with css position absolute and top/left/width in pixels.

But, with the data I have to display, that means adding 473 div for 39 different images (473 polygons out of ~10k need an image, 74 lines and 134 columns of hexes). The image represents the map of the world and the hexes can have about 40 different colors. You can see it [here](https://gitlab.com/zePierre/rfc5_atlas/-/raw/master/single_html.html?inline=false).

I was wondering if there was a solution to make that image appear on top of the hex, ideally in svg or in css? like adding a class to the polygon, or a style?

I have tried putting a style to a polygon and giving it a background-image, contain the image within the polygon, but the color of the polygon prevails on top.

Here is the code with:

- the first polygon of the first line with an image over it thanks to the div solution
- the last polygon of the second line with a CSS changing color into orange but failing to add an image on top of the orange (and even with fill:none !?)

```css
.imageOnTop {
  fill:orange;
  stroke:black;
  background-image: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4bd89893bb55d58180443e45eca3163e?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1');
  background-size: contain;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="mapBody">
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="150">
            <polygon points="0,90 15,81 30,90 30,108 15,117 0,108" fill="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="30,90 45,81 60,90 60,108 45,117 30,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="60,90 75,81 90,90 90,108 75,117 60,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="90,90 105,81 120,90 120,108 105,117 90,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="120,90 135,81 150,90 150,108 135,117 120,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="150,90 165,81 180,90 180,108 165,117 150,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="180,90 195,81 210,90 210,108 195,117 180,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="210,90 225,81 240,90 240,108 225,117 210,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="15,63 30,54 45,63 45,81 30,90 15,81" fill="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="45,63 60,54 75,63 75,81 60,90 45,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="75,63 90,54 105,63 105,81 90,90 75,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="105,63 120,54 135,63 135,81 120,90 105,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="135,63 150,54 165,63 165,81 150,90 135,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="165,63 180,54 195,63 195,81 180,90 165,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="195,63 210,54 225,63 225,81 210,90 195,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="225,63 240,54 255,63 255,81 240,90 225,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,36 15,27 30,36 30,54 15,63 0,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="30,36 45,27 60,36 60,54 45,63 30,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="60,36 75,27 90,36 90,54 75,63 60,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="90,36 105,27 120,36 120,54 105,63 90,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="120,36 135,27 150,36 150,54 135,63 120,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="150,36 165,27 180,36 180,54 165,63 150,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="180,36 195,27 210,36 210,54 195,63 180,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <!-- LOOK AT THIS ONE --> <polygon points="210,36 225,27 240,36 240,54 225,63 210,54" fill="black" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1" class="imageOnTop"></polygon> <!-- LOOK AT THIS ONE -->
            <polygon points="15,9 30,0 45,9 45,27 30,36 15,27" fill="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="45,9 60,0 75,9 75,27 60,36 45,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="75,9 90,0 105,9 105,27 90,36 75,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="105,9 120,0 135,9 135,27 120,36 105,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="135,9 150,0 165,9 165,27 150,36 135,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="165,9 180,0 195,9 195,27 180,36 165,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="195,9 210,0 225,9 225,27 210,36 195,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="225,9 240,0 255,9 255,27 240,36 225,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>

<div><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4bd89893bb55d58180443e45eca3163e?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" style="width: 20px; position: absolute; top: 15px; left: 25px;" /></div>
```

---

Below is an update of the question with a solution proposed to do this via `<defs><pattern ...><image ...>`

Thanks @Jing-Xian!!

Here is the solution for the image to appear via CSS and not to repeat:
(width has to match polygon width)

```css
.imageOnTop {
  fill:orange;
  fill:url(#img1);
  stroke:black;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="mapBody">
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="150">
        <defs>
          <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="34px" height="34px">
            <image href="https://i.ibb.co/0XGwpPz/resource-bison.png" x="4px" y="-5px" width="34px" height="34px" />
          </pattern>
        </defs>
            <polygon points="0,90 15,81 30,90 30,108 15,117 0,108" fill="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="30,90 45,81 60,90 60,108 45,117 30,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="60,90 75,81 90,90 90,108 75,117 60,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="90,90 105,81 120,90 120,108 105,117 90,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="120,90 135,81 150,90 150,108 135,117 120,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="150,90 165,81 180,90 180,108 165,117 150,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="180,90 195,81 210,90 210,108 195,117 180,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="210,90 225,81 240,90 240,108 225,117 210,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="15,63 30,54 45,63 45,81 30,90 15,81" fill="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="45,63 60,54 75,63 75,81 60,90 45,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="75,63 90,54 105,63 105,81 90,90 75,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="105,63 120,54 135,63 135,81 120,90 105,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="135,63 150,54 165,63 165,81 150,90 135,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="165,63 180,54 195,63 195,81 180,90 165,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="195,63 210,54 225,63 225,81 210,90 195,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="225,63 240,54 255,63 255,81 240,90 225,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,36 15,27 30,36 30,54 15,63 0,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="30,36 45,27 60,36 60,54 45,63 30,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="60,36 75,27 90,36 90,54 75,63 60,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="90,36 105,27 120,36 120,54 105,63 90,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="120,36 135,27 150,36 150,54 135,63 120,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="150,36 165,27 180,36 180,54 165,63 150,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="180,36 195,27 210,36 210,54 195,63 180,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <!-- LOOK AT THIS ONE --> <polygon points="210,36 225,27 240,36 240,54 225,63 210,54" fill="orange" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1" class="imageOnTop"></polygon> <!-- LOOK AT THIS ONE -->
            <polygon points="15,9 30,0 45,9 45,27 30,36 15,27" fill="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="45,9 60,0 75,9 75,27 60,36 45,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="75,9 90,0 105,9 105,27 90,36 75,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="105,9 120,0 135,9 135,27 120,36 105,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="135,9 150,0 165,9 165,27 150,36 135,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="165,9 180,0 195,9 195,27 180,36 165,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="195,9 210,0 225,9 225,27 210,36 195,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="225,9 240,0 255,9 255,27 240,36 225,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>

<div><img src="https://i.ibb.co/0XGwpPz/resource-bison.png" style="width: 30px; position: absolute; top: 11px; left: 22px;" /></div>
```

**But one problem remains: if the image is displayed this way, the background color of the polygon disappears (despite the PNG being transparent).**

---

Proposed by MXDVL: add a rect into the pattern.

But that rect appears above the image, not under. Plus I have 30 different colors for the hexes and 39 different images to add as overlay. That would mean more than 1000 pattern to be defined. :/

```css
.imageOnTop {
  fill:orange;
  fill:url(#img1);
  stroke:black;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="mapBody">
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="150">
        <defs>
          <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="34px" height="34px">
          
            <image href="https://i.ibb.co/0XGwpPz/resource-bison.png" x="4px" y="-5px" width="34px" height="34px" />
            <rect width="20" height="20" fill="orange">
          </pattern>
        </defs>
            <polygon points="0,90 15,81 30,90 30,108 15,117 0,108" fill="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="30,90 45,81 60,90 60,108 45,117 30,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="60,90 75,81 90,90 90,108 75,117 60,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="90,90 105,81 120,90 120,108 105,117 90,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="120,90 135,81 150,90 150,108 135,117 120,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="150,90 165,81 180,90 180,108 165,117 150,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="180,90 195,81 210,90 210,108 195,117 180,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="210,90 225,81 240,90 240,108 225,117 210,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="15,63 30,54 45,63 45,81 30,90 15,81" fill="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="45,63 60,54 75,63 75,81 60,90 45,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="75,63 90,54 105,63 105,81 90,90 75,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="105,63 120,54 135,63 135,81 120,90 105,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="135,63 150,54 165,63 165,81 150,90 135,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="165,63 180,54 195,63 195,81 180,90 165,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="195,63 210,54 225,63 225,81 210,90 195,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="225,63 240,54 255,63 255,81 240,90 225,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,36 15,27 30,36 30,54 15,63 0,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="30,36 45,27 60,36 60,54 45,63 30,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="60,36 75,27 90,36 90,54 75,63 60,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="90,36 105,27 120,36 120,54 105,63 90,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="120,36 135,27 150,36 150,54 135,63 120,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="150,36 165,27 180,36 180,54 165,63 150,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="180,36 195,27 210,36 210,54 195,63 180,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <!-- LOOK AT THIS ONE --> <polygon points="210,36 225,27 240,36 240,54 225,63 210,54" fill="orange" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1" class="imageOnTop"></polygon> <!-- LOOK AT THIS ONE -->
            <polygon points="15,9 30,0 45,9 45,27 30,36 15,27" fill="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="45,9 60,0 75,9 75,27 60,36 45,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="75,9 90,0 105,9 105,27 90,36 75,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="105,9 120,0 135,9 135,27 120,36 105,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="135,9 150,0 165,9 165,27 150,36 135,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="165,9 180,0 195,9 195,27 180,36 165,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="195,9 210,0 225,9 225,27 210,36 195,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="225,9 240,0 255,9 255,27 240,36 225,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>

<div><img src="https://i.ibb.co/0XGwpPz/resource-bison.png" style="width: 30px; position: absolute; top: 11px; left: 22px;" /></div>
```

Result
[image]

Comment: Have you tried a div with a psuedo element? Also if the color of the polygon prevails on top try position: relative and z-index

Comment: I tried and updated the question to clarify / better present code. How would you used a div with a pseudo element? I don't see how it applies here?

Comment: *I have a svg generated by javascript and included inline in the HTML page.*--> I would start fixing this.  You can generate you grid with SVG at all and using only CSS (check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65684164/8620333)

Comment: ^ I meant without* SVG

Comment: @TemaniAfif that code in your link and rendering is beautiful <3 but why is the svg inline something to fix? :-) (true question) It enables to easily offer the user the possibility to download the image. https://gitlab.com/zePierre/rfc5_atlas/-/raw/master/single_html.html?inline=false With the div and css won't I have the same issue, having either the background color OR the background image, but not both?

Comment: as you have noticed, mixing SVG and CSS is not easy. Either you build everything using CSS like the link I shared (it will be easy to add image there) or you re-think your SVG logic to make it easy to add image (I am not expert with SVG to help with this task)

Comment: @Pierre please check my solution when you have a chance. It accomplishes both tasks, using a custom fill color as well as displaying the image, by creating both as layers within a `<pattern>` element.

Comment: @Pierre could you please check my solution when you have a chance? If it works for you, please consider accepting my answer as the chosen solution for this question.

Comment: sorry I had to move to other features, but I'll check & accept by tomorrow, thanks a lot for replying!

Comment: @Pierre no worries. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the other solutions were on the right track. All you need to do is to add another layer to your `<pattern>` with the fill color you want. You can make this color static and define it explicitly in the SVG/HTML or within the CSS.

If you'd like even more flexibility, rather than adding the `<rect>` to the `<pattern>`, you can group each polygon with a duplicate polygon, use the first for the `background-color`, and the second for the pattern `fill`. This allows all of those properties (`stroke`, `stroke-opacity`, `fill`, and more) independently. In this **#2** solution, I've also added `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"` to the `<pattern>` to ensure that the background image is always centered, without needing to manually set the `x` and `y` each time to recenter the fill image.

For solution **#2**, please scroll down.

### 1. Adding a static fill color to the `<pattern>` (#2 below)

```css
.imageOnTop {
  fill: url(#img1);
  stroke: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="mapBody">
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="150">
        <defs>
          <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="34px" height="34px">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="orange" />
            <image href="https://i.ibb.co/0XGwpPz/resource-bison.png" x="4px" y="-5px" width="34px" height="34px" />
          </pattern>
        </defs>
            <polygon points="0,90 15,81 30,90 30,108 15,117 0,108" fill="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="30,90 45,81 60,90 60,108 45,117 30,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="60,90 75,81 90,90 90,108 75,117 60,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="90,90 105,81 120,90 120,108 105,117 90,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="120,90 135,81 150,90 150,108 135,117 120,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="150,90 165,81 180,90 180,108 165,117 150,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="180,90 195,81 210,90 210,108 195,117 180,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="210,90 225,81 240,90 240,108 225,117 210,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="15,63 30,54 45,63 45,81 30,90 15,81" fill="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="45,63 60,54 75,63 75,81 60,90 45,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="75,63 90,54 105,63 105,81 90,90 75,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="105,63 120,54 135,63 135,81 120,90 105,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="135,63 150,54 165,63 165,81 150,90 135,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="165,63 180,54 195,63 195,81 180,90 165,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="195,63 210,54 225,63 225,81 210,90 195,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="225,63 240,54 255,63 255,81 240,90 225,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,36 15,27 30,36 30,54 15,63 0,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="30,36 45,27 60,36 60,54 45,63 30,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="60,36 75,27 90,36 90,54 75,63 60,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="90,36 105,27 120,36 120,54 105,63 90,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="120,36 135,27 150,36 150,54 135,63 120,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="150,36 165,27 180,36 180,54 165,63 150,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="180,36 195,27 210,36 210,54 195,63 180,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <!-- LOOK AT THIS ONE --> <polygon points="210,36 225,27 240,36 240,54 225,63 210,54" fill="orange" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1" class="imageOnTop"></polygon> <!-- LOOK AT THIS ONE -->
            <polygon points="15,9 30,0 45,9 45,27 30,36 15,27" fill="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="45,9 60,0 75,9 75,27 60,36 45,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="75,9 90,0 105,9 105,27 90,36 75,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="105,9 120,0 135,9 135,27 120,36 105,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="135,9 150,0 165,9 165,27 150,36 135,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="165,9 180,0 195,9 195,27 180,36 165,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="195,9 210,0 225,9 225,27 210,36 195,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="225,9 240,0 255,9 255,27 240,36 225,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

### 2. Grouping polygons to separate fill color and fill image independently

```css
.imageOnTop {
  --blink-color: orange;
  --animation-duration: 0.75s;
}
.imageOnTop > polygon:first-child {
  animation: blink-fill ease-in-out var(--animation-duration) infinite alternate both;
}
.imageOnTop > polygon:last-child {
  fill: url(#img1);
  animation: blink-stroke ease-in-out var(--animation-duration) infinite alternate both;
}
@keyframes blink-fill {
  from { fill: var(--start-color) }
    to { fill: var(--blink-color) }
}
@keyframes blink-stroke {
  from { stroke-opacity: 0 }
    to { stroke-opacity: 1 }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="mapBody">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="150">
      <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" viewBox="0 0 30 36" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
          <image width="30" height="36" xlink:href="https://i.ibb.co/0XGwpPz/resource-bison.png"/>
        </pattern>
      </defs>
      <g class="imageOnTop" style="--blink-color: #f0f">
        <polygon points="0,90 15,81 30,90 30,108 15,117 0,108" fill="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(150,183,243)" />
        <polygon points="0,90 15,81 30,90 30,108 15,117 0,108" fill="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="30,90 45,81 60,90 60,108 45,117 30,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="30,90 45,81 60,90 60,108 45,117 30,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="60,90 75,81 90,90 90,108 75,117 60,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="60,90 75,81 90,90 90,108 75,117 60,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="90,90 105,81 120,90 120,108 105,117 90,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="90,90 105,81 120,90 120,108 105,117 90,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g class="imageOnTop" style="--blink-color: #0f0">
        <polygon points="120,90 135,81 150,90 150,108 135,117 120,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="120,90 135,81 150,90 150,108 135,117 120,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="150,90 165,81 180,90 180,108 165,117 150,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="150,90 165,81 180,90 180,108 165,117 150,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="180,90 195,81 210,90 210,108 195,117 180,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="180,90 195,81 210,90 210,108 195,117 180,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="210,90 225,81 240,90 240,108 225,117 210,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="210,90 225,81 240,90 240,108 225,117 210,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="15,63 30,54 45,63 45,81 30,90 15,81" fill="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(150,183,243)" />
        <polygon points="15,63 30,54 45,63 45,81 30,90 15,81" fill="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="45,63 60,54 75,63 75,81 60,90 45,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="45,63 60,54 75,63 75,81 60,90 45,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="75,63 90,54 105,63 105,81 90,90 75,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="75,63 90,54 105,63 105,81 90,90 75,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="105,63 120,54 135,63 135,81 120,90 105,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="105,63 120,54 135,63 135,81 120,90 105,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="135,63 150,54 165,63 165,81 150,90 135,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="135,63 150,54 165,63 165,81 150,90 135,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="165,63 180,54 195,63 195,81 180,90 165,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="165,63 180,54 195,63 195,81 180,90 165,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="195,63 210,54 225,63 225,81 210,90 195,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="195,63 210,54 225,63 225,81 210,90 195,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="225,63 240,54 255,63 255,81 240,90 225,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="225,63 240,54 255,63 255,81 240,90 225,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="0,36 15,27 30,36 30,54 15,63 0,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="0,36 15,27 30,36 30,54 15,63 0,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="30,36 45,27 60,36 60,54 45,63 30,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="30,36 45,27 60,36 60,54 45,63 30,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="60,36 75,27 90,36 90,54 75,63 60,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="60,36 75,27 90,36 90,54 75,63 60,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="90,36 105,27 120,36 120,54 105,63 90,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="90,36 105,27 120,36 120,54 105,63 90,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="120,36 135,27 150,36 150,54 135,63 120,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="120,36 135,27 150,36 150,54 135,63 120,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="150,36 165,27 180,36 180,54 165,63 150,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="150,36 165,27 180,36 180,54 165,63 150,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="180,36 195,27 210,36 210,54 195,63 180,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="180,36 195,27 210,36 210,54 195,63 180,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g class="imageOnTop">
        <polygon points="210,36 225,27 240,36 240,54 225,63 210,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="210,36 225,27 240,36 240,54 225,63 210,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="15,9 30,0 45,9 45,27 30,36 15,27" fill="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(150,183,243)" />
        <polygon points="15,9 30,0 45,9 45,27 30,36 15,27" fill="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="45,9 60,0 75,9 75,27 60,36 45,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="45,9 60,0 75,9 75,27 60,36 45,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="75,9 90,0 105,9 105,27 90,36 75,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="75,9 90,0 105,9 105,27 90,36 75,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="105,9 120,0 135,9 135,27 120,36 105,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="105,9 120,0 135,9 135,27 120,36 105,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="135,9 150,0 165,9 165,27 150,36 135,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="135,9 150,0 165,9 165,27 150,36 135,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="165,9 180,0 195,9 195,27 180,36 165,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="165,9 180,0 195,9 195,27 180,36 165,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="195,9 210,0 225,9 225,27 210,36 195,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="195,9 210,0 225,9 225,27 210,36 195,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g><g>
        <polygon points="225,9 240,0 255,9 255,27 240,36 225,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" style="--start-color: rgb(83,126,162)" />
        <polygon points="225,9 240,0 255,9 255,27 240,36 225,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, just a note— I intentionally created the faint white border between the hex cells in my **#2** solution, but if you don't want that, it's just one simple code change to remove them.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! That's awesome! I have only kept a single CSS instruction and included it into the defs part of the SVG.

Comment: Glad to hear, @Pierre! Yes, that should work just fine. I'd love to see the finished product. By grouping via `<g>` you add a lot more flexibility as far as style goes, allowing you to assign any number of different colors for different blocks, even via CSS custom properties with only one pattern per image in the `<defs>`.

Comment: `<g>` is definitely my new friend :) I cannot paste images in comments, but the repo is here https://gitlab.com/zePierre/rfc5_atlas and the portable version can be downloaded here to have a quick look: https://gitlab.com/zePierre/rfc5_atlas/-/raw/master/single_html.html?inline=false - thanks again, the divs were really getting messy to align onto the hexes each time something moved on the page...

Comment: You could also opt against SVG altogether and go for something more custom using CSS Grid which would offer much more flexibility. Here's a quick example I threw together, recreating a generic Settlers of Catan board layout using CSS Grid and keeping all the same responsive benefits of SVG: https://cdpn.io/e/RwpoEYy

Comment: Yes that's what @temani-afif suggested also, it's very impressive, but for me it's easier to manipulate SVG than CSS :s thanks!

Comment: @Pierre Sure thing!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by setting the background into a pattern and set the style of fill as the pattern.

```css
.imageOnTop {
  fill:url(#img1);
  stroke:black;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="mapBody">
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="150">
        <defs>
          <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="20px" height="20px">
            <image href="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4bd89893bb55d58180443e45eca3163e?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" x="0" y="0" width="20px" height="20px" />
          </pattern>
        </defs>
            <polygon points="0,90 15,81 30,90 30,108 15,117 0,108" fill="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="30,90 45,81 60,90 60,108 45,117 30,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="60,90 75,81 90,90 90,108 75,117 60,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="90,90 105,81 120,90 120,108 105,117 90,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="120,90 135,81 150,90 150,108 135,117 120,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="150,90 165,81 180,90 180,108 165,117 150,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="180,90 195,81 210,90 210,108 195,117 180,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="210,90 225,81 240,90 240,108 225,117 210,108" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="15,63 30,54 45,63 45,81 30,90 15,81" fill="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="45,63 60,54 75,63 75,81 60,90 45,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="75,63 90,54 105,63 105,81 90,90 75,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="105,63 120,54 135,63 135,81 120,90 105,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="135,63 150,54 165,63 165,81 150,90 135,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="165,63 180,54 195,63 195,81 180,90 165,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="195,63 210,54 225,63 225,81 210,90 195,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="225,63 240,54 255,63 255,81 240,90 225,81" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,36 15,27 30,36 30,54 15,63 0,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="30,36 45,27 60,36 60,54 45,63 30,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="60,36 75,27 90,36 90,54 75,63 60,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="90,36 105,27 120,36 120,54 105,63 90,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="120,36 135,27 150,36 150,54 135,63 120,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="150,36 165,27 180,36 180,54 165,63 150,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="180,36 195,27 210,36 210,54 195,63 180,54" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <!-- LOOK AT THIS ONE --> <polygon points="210,36 225,27 240,36 240,54 225,63 210,54" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1" class="imageOnTop"></polygon> <!-- LOOK AT THIS ONE -->
            <polygon points="15,9 30,0 45,9 45,27 30,36 15,27" fill="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke="rgb(150,183,243)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="45,9 60,0 75,9 75,27 60,36 45,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="75,9 90,0 105,9 105,27 90,36 75,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="105,9 120,0 135,9 135,27 120,36 105,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="135,9 150,0 165,9 165,27 150,36 135,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="165,9 180,0 195,9 195,27 180,36 165,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="195,9 210,0 225,9 225,27 210,36 195,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="225,9 240,0 255,9 255,27 240,36 225,27" fill="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke="rgb(83,126,162)" stroke-width="1"></polygon>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>

<div><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4bd89893bb55d58180443e45eca3163e?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" style="width: 20px; position: absolute; top: 15px; left: 25px;" /></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't want the image to repeat so I made sure width would match polygon width. I put the code in a new answer. One problem remains: if the image is displayed this way, the background color of the polygon disappears (despite the image being transparent PNG, as it works with the <div> solution).

Comment: @Pierre you need to add a filled rectangle behind you image in the `pattern`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Pierre you need to add a filled rectangle behind you image in the `pattern`.

```
<pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="34px" height="34px">
<rect width="34" height="34" fill="orange">
  <image href="https://upload.picpaste.me/images/2021/05/08/resource_0_iron.png" x="4px" y="-5px" width="34px" height="34px" />
</pattern>
```

Comment: Thank you, but that rect appears above the image, not under. Plus I have 30 different colors for the hexes and 39 different images to add as overlay. That would mean more than 1000 pattern to be defined. :/ I updated the question post with your proposed solution

Comment: Oops, of course order matters. I’ve edited the answer. 

Another approach would be to use the image as the fill’s <paint>: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Content_type

Comment: Using this pattern (with rect first and image second) I see only the color and no image :/