# How to create a hexagonal chess board with css?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm seeking assistance with a web development project where I aim to recreate the visual representation of [this hexagonal chess board](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/thumb/9/94/HexagonalschachFelder.svg/220px-HexagonalschachFelder.svg.png) using CSS and HTML. My goal is to replicate the chessboard's grid structure without including the accompanying text.

As of now, I've made some progress with my code, but I'm encountering difficulties completing the task. Here's what I've achieved so far:

```css
.board{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(11, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 770px;
    height: 770px;
  }
  
.board> .column {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns:1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(11, 1fr);
}
.board> .column:nth-child(odd){
    transform: translateY(-35px) translateX(17.5px);
}

.board> .column div {
    width: auto;
    height: 70px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%);
  }

.board> .column div.field:nth-child(even) {
    background: rebeccapurple;
  }

.board> .column div.field:nth-child(odd) {
    background: wheat;
  }
```

```html
<div class="board">
        <div class="column">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div class="field"></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: HTML *really* isn't designed for this. If you want to generate diagrams on a website then I strongly recommend SVG.

Comment: Maybe try a smaller grid at the beginning, rotate 90° so that all cell of a line are contiguous. I don't understand why your div are not the same number as in your image example, maybe explain it. (I expected 6 cells, then 7 8 9 10 11 then again 10 9 8 7 6)

Comment: check this: https://css-tricks.com/hexagons-and-beyond-flexible-responsive-grid-patterns-sans-media-queries/

Comment: You can also check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114920/responsive-grid-of-hexagons

Comment: You can use CSS grid as you have tried see e.g. https://ninjarockstar.dev/css-hex-grids/ but @TemaniAfif method seems more straightforward to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to implement what you want to do with HTML and CSS. It's not elegant, but it should work.

I found a solution with `display-flex`. One advantage of this approach is that you don't have empty cells and they are in correct order in the code.

```css
    #board {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-content: flex-start;
        height: 40em;
    }
    
    .col {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
        width: 50px;
        margin: 14.5px;
    }
    
    .cell {
        position: relative;
        width: 50px;
        height: 86.603px;
        margin: 2px;
        background-color: red;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 86.603px;
    }
    
    .cell::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        left: -25px;
        border-right: 25px solid red;
        border-top: 43.302px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 43.302px solid transparent;
        border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    }
    
    .cell::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        left: 50px;
        border-left: 25px solid red;
        border-top: 43.302px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 43.302px solid transparent;
        border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    }
    
    .col:nth-child(5),
    .col:nth-child(7) {
        margin-top: 43.302px;
    }
    
    .col:nth-child(4),
    .col:nth-child(8) {
        margin-top: 86.603px;
    }
    
    .col:nth-child(3),
    .col:nth-child(9) {
        margin-top: 129.904px;
    }

    .col:nth-child(2),
    .col:nth-child(10) {
        margin-top: 173.206px;
    }
    
    .col:nth-child(1),
    .col:nth-child(11) {
        margin-top: 216.507px;  
    }
    
    .col:nth-child(6) {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 6) .cell:nth-child(3n),
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 7) .cell:nth-child(3n + 1),
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 8) .cell:nth-child(3n + 2) {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 6) .cell:nth-child(3n)::before,
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 7) .cell:nth-child(3n + 1)::before,
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 8) .cell:nth-child(3n + 2)::before {
        border-right-color: blue;
    }

    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 6) .cell:nth-child(3n)::after,
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 7) .cell:nth-child(3n + 1)::after,
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 8) .cell:nth-child(3n + 2)::after {
        border-left-color: blue;
    }

    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 6) .cell:nth-child(3n + 1),
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 7) .cell:nth-child(3n + 2),
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 8) .cell:nth-child(3n) {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 6) .cell:nth-child(3n + 1)::before,
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 7) .cell:nth-child(3n + 2)::before,
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 8) .cell:nth-child(3n)::before {
        border-right-color: yellow;
    }
    
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 6) .cell:nth-child(3n + 1)::after,
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 7) .cell:nth-child(3n + 2)::after,
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 8) .cell:nth-child(3n)::after {
        border-left-color: yellow;
    }
    
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 6) .cell:nth-child(3n + 2),
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 7) .cell:nth-child(3n),
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 8) .cell:nth-child(3n + 1) {
        background-color: green;
    }
    
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 6) .cell:nth-child(3n + 2)::before,
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 7) .cell:nth-child(3n)::before,
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 8) .cell:nth-child(3n + 1)::before {
        border-right-color: green;
    }
    
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 6) .cell:nth-child(3n + 2)::after,
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 7) .cell:nth-child(3n)::after,
    .col:nth-last-child(3n + 8) .cell:nth-child(3n + 1)::after {
        border-left-color: green;
    }
    
    .col:nth-child(3n + 6) .cell:nth-child(3n),
    .col:nth-child(3n + 7) .cell:nth-child(3n + 1),
    .col:nth-child(3n + 8) .cell:nth-child(3n + 2) {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    
    .col:nth-child(3n + 6) .cell:nth-child(3n)::before,
    .col:nth-child(3n + 7) .cell:nth-child(3n + 1)::before,
    .col:nth-child(3n + 8) .cell:nth-child(3n + 2)::before {
        border-right-color: blue;
    }
    
    .col:nth-child(3n + 6) .cell:nth-child(3n)::after,
    .col:nth-child(3n + 7) .cell:nth-child(3n + 1)::after,
    .col:nth-child(3n + 8) .cell:nth-child(3n + 2)::after {
        border-left-color: blue;
    }
    
    .col:nth-child(3n + 6) .cell:nth-child(3n + 1),
    .col:nth-child(3n + 7) .cell:nth-child(3n + 2),
    .col:nth-child(3n + 8) .cell:nth-child(3n) {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    .col:nth-child(3n + 6) .cell:nth-child(3n + 1)::before,
    .col:nth-child(3n + 7) .cell:nth-child(3n + 2)::before,
    .col:nth-child(3n + 8) .cell:nth-child(3n)::before {
        border-right-color: yellow;
    }
    
    .col:nth-child(3n + 6) .cell:nth-child(3n + 1)::after,
    .col:nth-child(3n + 7) .cell:nth-child(3n + 2)::after,
    .col:nth-child(3n + 8) .cell:nth-child(3n)::after {
        border-left-color: yellow;
    }
    
    .col:nth-child(3n + 6) .cell:nth-child(3n + 2),
    .col:nth-child(3n + 7) .cell:nth-child(3n),
    .col:nth-child(3n + 8) .cell:nth-child(3n + 1) {
        background-color: green;
    }

    .col:nth-child(3n + 6) .cell:nth-child(3n + 2)::before,
    .col:nth-child(3n + 7) .cell:nth-child(3n)::before,
    .col:nth-child(3n + 8) .cell:nth-child(3n + 1)::before {
        border-right-color: green;
    }

    .col:nth-child(3n + 6) .cell:nth-child(3n + 2)::after,
    .col:nth-child(3n + 7) .cell:nth-child(3n)::after,
    .col:nth-child(3n + 8) .cell:nth-child(3n + 1)::after {
        border-left-color: green;
    }
```

```html
<div id="board">
        <div id="col-A" class="col">
            <div id="a-1" class="cell">a-1</div>
            <div id="a-2" class="cell">a-2</div>
            <div id="a-3" class="cell">a-3</div>
            <div id="a-4" class="cell">a-4</div>
            <div id="a-5" class="cell">a-5</div>
            <div id="a-6" class="cell">a-6</div>
        </div>
        <div id="col-B" class="col">
            <div id="2-1" class="cell">b-1</div>
            <div id="b-2" class="cell">b-2</div>
            <div id="b-3" class="cell">b-3</div>
            <div id="b-4" class="cell">b-4</div>
            <div id="b-5" class="cell">b-5</div>
            <div id="b-6" class="cell">b-6</div>
            <div id="b-7" class="cell">b-7</div>
        </div>
        <div id="col-C" class="col">
            <div id="c-1" class="cell">c-1</div>
            <div id="c-2" class="cell">c-2</div>
            <div id="c-3" class="cell">c-3</div>
            <div id="c-4" class="cell">c-4</div>
            <div id="c-5" class="cell">c-5</div>
            <div id="c-6" class="cell">c-6</div>
            <div id="c-7" class="cell">c-7</div>
            <div id="c-8" class="cell">c-8</div>
        </div>
        <div id="col-D" class="col">
            <div id="d-1" class="cell">d-1</div>
            <div id="d-2" class="cell">d-2</div>
            <div id="d-3" class="cell">d-3</div>
            <div id="d-4" class="cell">d-4</div>
            <div id="d-5" class="cell">d-5</div>
            <div id="d-6" class="cell">d-6</div>
            <div id="d-7" class="cell">d-7</div>
            <div id="d-8" class="cell">d-8</div>
            <div id="d-9" class="cell">d-9</div>
        </div>
        <div id="col-E" class="col">
            <div id="e-1" class="cell">e-1</div>
            <div id="e-2" class="cell">e-2</div>
            <div id="e-3" class="cell">e-3</div>
            <div id="e-4" class="cell">e-4</div>
            <div id="e-5" class="cell">e-5</div>
            <div id="e-6" class="cell">e-6</div>
            <div id="e-7" class="cell">e-7</div>
            <div id="e-8" class="cell">e-8</div>
            <div id="e-9" class="cell">e-9</div>
            <div id="e-10" class="cell">e-10</div>
        </div>
        <div id="col-F" class="col">
            <div id="f-1" class="cell">f-1</div>
            <div id="f-2" class="cell">f-2</div>
            <div id="f-3" class="cell">f-3</div>
            <div id="f-4" class="cell">f-4</div>
            <div id="f-5" class="cell">f-5</div>
            <div id="f-6" class="cell">f-6</div>
            <div id="f-7" class="cell">f-7</div>
            <div id="f-8" class="cell">f-8</div>
            <div id="f-9" class="cell">f-9</div>
            <div id="f-10" class="cell">f-10</div>
            <div id="f-11" class="cell">f-11</div>
        </div>
        <div id="col-G" class="col">
            <div id="g-1" class="cell">g-1</div>
            <div id="g-2" class="cell">g-2</div>
            <div id="g-3" class="cell">g-3</div>
            <div id="g-4" class="cell">g-4</div>
            <div id="g-5" class="cell">g-5</div>
            <div id="g-6" class="cell">g-6</div>
            <div id="g-7" class="cell">g-7</div>
            <div id="g-8" class="cell">g-8</div>
            <div id="g-9" class="cell">g-9</div>
            <div id="g-10" class="cell">g-10</div>
        </div>
        <div id="col-H" class="col">
            <div id="h-1" class="cell">h-1</div>
            <div id="h-2" class="cell">h-2</div>
            <div id="h-3" class="cell">h-3</div>
            <div id="h-4" class="cell">h-4</div>
            <div id="h-5" class="cell">h-5</div>
            <div id="h-6" class="cell">h-6</div>
            <div id="h-7" class="cell">h-7</div>
            <div id="h-8" class="cell">h-8</div>
            <div id="h-9" class="cell">h-9</div>
        </div>
        <div id="col-I" class="col">
            <div id="i-1" class="cell">i-1</div>
            <div id="i-2" class="cell">i-2</div>
            <div id="i-3" class="cell">i-3</div>
            <div id="i-4" class="cell">i-4</div>
            <div id="i-5" class="cell">i-5</div>
            <div id="i-6" class="cell">i-6</div>
            <div id="i-7" class="cell">i-7</div>
            <div id="i-8" class="cell">i-8</div>
        </div>
        <div id="col-K" class="col">
            <div id="k-1" class="cell">k-1</div>
            <div id="k-2" class="cell">k-2</div>
            <div id="k-3" class="cell">k-3</div>
            <div id="k-4" class="cell">k-4</div>
            <div id="k-5" class="cell">k-5</div>
            <div id="k-6" class="cell">k-6</div>
            <div id="k-7" class="cell">k-7</div>
        </div>
        <div id="col-L" class="col">
            <div id="l-1" class="cell">l-1</div>
            <div id="l-2" class="cell">l-2</div>
            <div id="l-3" class="cell">l-3</div>
            <div id="l-4" class="cell">l-4</div>
            <div id="l-5" class="cell">l-5</div>
            <div id="l-6" class="cell">l-6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I still have a small problem tho. As you can see here , sometimes there are some weird vertical lines. Why is that? Is that a css problem or the browser or something? Also, how can I make it resizable? You should be able to resize the board.

Comment: I think the white lines are from rounding the sizing. To get rid of them, you can set for `.cell::before` the value of `left` a little smaller than `25px`, e.g. `24.8px`.

Comment: And to make it resizable, just use another unit (e.g. `vw` or `vh`) and adjust all the sizes. The ratio of the width to the height of the cells (`.cell`) is a : a√3. The `border-top` and `border-bottom` of `.cell::before` and `.cell::after` is a  a√3 / 2. The `margin-top` values of `.col:nth-child(x)` are multiples of a√3 / 2.